# TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am pretty new to MSTest and I am getting the below error while running the below test. I couldn't make much out of the the exception though.

Request your help with this! I am also attaching the test method code below.

[image]

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetReturnsAllSolutionsForAdminUser()
{
    var storageService = new Mock<IStorageService>();
    AuthenticatedUsername = "xxx@yyy.com";

    var mockStorage = new Mock<IStorageService>();
    var mockGeneralServices = new Mock<IGeneralServices>();
    var mockDesignerEngine = new Mock<IDesignerEngine>();
    var mockExcelUploadService = new Mock<ISolutionBuilderFromExcelService>();


    var solutions = new List<Solution>(
        new[]
        {
            new Solution
            {
                Id = "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                Name = "Solution 1",
                Description = "Description Of Solution 1",
                ResourceGroups = new NamedItemList<ResourceGroup>(new[] {new ResourceGroup{Name="Solution 1:ResourceGroup 1"}}),
                CreatedBy = "xxx@yyy.com",
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("05/05/2018"),
                Version = "1.0.1",
                TaggingEnabled = true,
            }
        }
    );
    storageService.Setup(it => it.ReadItemsAsync<Solution>()).ReturnsAsync(solutions);


    var controller = new SolutionsController(mockGeneralServices.Object, mockStorage.Object, mockDesignerEngine.Object, mockExcelUploadService.Object)
    {
        ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = GetMockHttpContext(CloudSuiteRoles.AdminRole, CloudSuiteRoles.UserRole).Object
        }
    };

    var result = await controller.Get().ConfigureAwait(false) as JsonResult;
    var items = result.Value as IEnumerable<dynamic>;//
    Assert.IsNotNull(items);
    Assert.AreEqual(solutions.Count(), items.Count());
}
```

Comment: not seeing where the `storageService` is being used in the test and how it relates to the subject under test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing where the `storageService` is being used in the test and how it relates to the subject under test.

You most likely meant to to `Setup` the `mockStorage`

Replace

```
storageService.Setup(it => it.ReadItemsAsync<Solution>()).ReturnsAsync(solutions);
```

with

```
mockStorage.Setup(_ => _.ReadItemsAsync<Solution>()).ReturnsAsync(solutions);
```

as that is the one being injected into the controller being tested.

The error is because the asyc method being called has not been mocked and the method is unable to flow to completion.